# Is $A = Q^TDQ = QDQ^T$ ($A$ is $n\times n$ matrix, $D$ is diagonal matrix and $Q$ is orthogonal eigenvector matrix)?

Tags: linear-algebra

If $A$ is orthogonally diagonalisable, then $D = Q^TAQ.$ Also, $D = Q^TAQ \to A^m = QD^mQ^T$ where $m \in \mathbb Z.$

Since similarity of matrices is an equivalence relation, $D = Q^TAQ \to A = Q^TDQ.$ Thus $A = Q^TDQ = QDQ^T$.

Does that make sense? The reason I ask this question is because while proving another result, I used $Q^TDQ$ instead of $QDQ^T$ so if the equality above holds I don't have to change my proof.

Comment: No, the equality may not be true.

Comment: “Equivalence relation” and “equality” are not the same thing.

Comment: @ amd, if $A$ is similar to $D$, then $D$ is similar to $A$ by symmetry, right? By definition, if  $A$ is similar to $D$, then $D = Q^TAQ$ and if $D$ is similar to $A$, then $A = Q^TDQ$. Does that make sense?

Comment: That is not true unless $Q^T=Q$ so you cannot use that in a general argument.

Comment: @ Test123, we always have $A = P^{-1}DP  = PDP^{-1}$ where $P$ is some eigenvector matrix, right? Can't we, then, have $A = Q^{-1}DQ  = QDQ^{-1}$ which implies(?) $A = Q^TDQ  = QDQ^T$ since $Q^T = Q^{-1}$?